# Player don't move if he shoot a bullet, c++ ncurses

Tags: c++, class, freeze, game-development, ncurses

I need to implement the shooting mechanics, but everytime that I shoot, the player movement freez.
I made a class for the shooting and I try to update the player movement everytime that the bullet moves; but it doesn't work. How can I fix that? I think that I need to change the code in the for.
This is the main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Personaggio.hpp"

bool gameover = false;

int main (){
    initscr();
    noecho();
    raw();
    cbreak();

    WINDOW * win = newwin (24, 80, 0, 0);
    refresh();
    box (win, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(win);
    keypad(win, TRUE);


    personaggio player(22, 24, '&', win);

    while (!gameover){
        wtimeout(win, 80);
        int movement = wgetch(win);

        if (movement==KEY_UP||movement==KEY_DOWN||movement==KEY_LEFT||movement==KEY_RIGHT){
            shoot *bullet = new shoot(player.cy(), player.cx(), '*', win);
            bullet->shooting(movement, player);

            delete bullet;
        }
        else {
            player.del();
            player.moving(movement);

            player.draw();
        }
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the player class:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

class personaggio {
protected:
    int currX, currY;
    int xMax, yMax;
    char character;
    WINDOW *window;
public:
    personaggio(int y, int x, char c, WINDOW *win) {
        window = win;
        getmaxyx(window, yMax, xMax);
        currX = x;
        currY = y;
        character= c;
    }

    void up() {
        mvwaddch(window, currY, currX, ' ');
        currY--;
        if (mvwinch(window, currY, currX) != 32 ||currY == 0) {
            currY++;
            refresh();
        }
    }

    void down() {
        mvwaddch(window, currY, currX, ' ');
        currY++;
        if (mvwinch(window, currY, currX) != 32 || currY == 23) {
            currY--;
            refresh();
        }
    }

    void right() {
        mvwaddch(window, currY, currX, ' ');
        currX++;
        if (mvwinch(window, currY, currX) != 32 || currX == 79) {
            currX--;
            refresh();
        }
    }

    void left() {
        mvwaddch(window, currY, currX, ' ');
        currX--;
        if (mvwinch(window, currY, currX) != 32 || currX == 0) {
            currX++;
            refresh();
        }
    }

    int moving(int movement) {
        switch (movement) {
            case 'w':
                up();
                break;
            case 's':
                down();
                break;
            case 'd':
                right();
                break;
            case 'a':
                left();
                break;
        }
        return movement;
    }


    void draw() {
        mvwaddch(window, currY, currX, character);
    }

    void del() {
        mvwaddch(window, currY, currX, ' ');
        wrefresh(window);
    }

    int cy() {
        return currY;
    }

    int cx() {
        return currX;
    }

};
```

This is the function inside the shooting class:

```
class shoot: public personaggio {
public:
    shoot(int y, int x, char c, WINDOW *window) : personaggio(y, x, c, window) {}

    int shooting(int movement, personaggio player) {
        switch (movement) {
            case KEY_UP:
                shootup(movement, player);
                break;
         /*   case KEY_DOWN:       //for now I am working only with KEY_UP
                shootdown();
                break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                shootrg();
                break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                shootlf();
                break;*/
            default:
                break;
        }
        return movement;
    }


    void shootup(int movement, personaggio player) {
        int tmp = currY;
        if (tmp != 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                tmp--;
                player.moving(movement);
                player.draw();
                wrefresh(window);
                if (mvwinch(window, tmp, currX) == 32) {
                    if (i != 4) {
                        draw(tmp);

                        napms(80);
                        del (tmp);
                    } else {
                        mvwaddch(window, tmp, currX, character);
                        wrefresh(window);

                        napms(80);
                        del(tmp);
                    }
                } else {
                    tmp++;
                    if (tmp != currY) {
                        mvwaddch(window, tmp, currX, '"');
                        wrefresh(window);
                        napms(100);

                        del(tmp);
                    }
                    i = 5;
                }
                player.del();
                wrefresh(window);
            }
        }
        move(currY, currX);
    }

    void del(int tmp){
        mvwaddch(window, tmp, currX, ' ');
        wrefresh(window);
    }

    void draw(int tmp) {
        mvwaddch(window, tmp, currX, ACS_BULLET);
        wrefresh(window);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not a complete program. I cannot copy'n'paste this and compile and run it. See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: ok, now you can copy'n'paste this

Comment: There's `sleep` in the for loop in `shooting`. With the current design, nothing else can happen while there is shooting.

Comment: I need it to make the effect of the shot. I try to update the player position every time but it doesn't work. Maybe I need another function instead of namps?